# go-run is giving me an error `cannot find package` on a relative submodule

Tags: go, go-modules

I have the following dir structure

```
~/test
 | lala
  - lala.go
 - main.go
```

And the contents:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "./lala"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(lala.asd)
}
```

lala.go:

```
package lala

import (
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"

        "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
)

func asd() string {
        return string(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32))
}
```

Then i execute:

```
~/test$ go mod init asdasd.com/asdasd
~/test$ go mod tidy
~/test$ go run main.go
```

But i get

`lala/lala.go:6:2: cannot find package`

That line is the one with the securecookie, which is a remote path.
I tried `go mod init && go mod tidy` in the lala dir but the error is the same.

Comment: Do not use relative imports.

Comment: Very helpfull. Wgats the solution then?

Comment: The opposite of relative paths are absolute paths. Please consult How to Write Go Code.

Answer (score 2):

Do not make use of relative paths in imports. Your import path should start with the project directory(The directory under src folder).

Change this

```
import  "./lala"
```

To

```
import  "asdasd.com/asdasd/lala"
```

Comment: Im not using GOROOT to manage this _project_. Im actually trying to break from GOROOT to prevent me from having to put the full url path on imports. I thought modules would help, but apparently, those are just as broken as GOPATH.

Comment: @AxelBayerl, GOROOT is never used to manage a project. “How to Write Go Code” walks you through what you want step by step.